# Se classes abstratas e interfaces não podem ser instanciadas, o que está acontecendo aqui?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, interface

Descobri que interfaces e classes abstratas não podem ser instanciadas, porém meu professor me passou um exemplo que me deixou na dúvida, porque me parece muito uma instância da `interface` `ActionListener`.

Segue o código:

```
ActionListener tarefa = (new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        HORAS();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Elas sozinhas não podem ser instanciadas, mas isso não é uma regra cega que foi criada, existe um motivo: não pode porque a interface não tem uma implementação e portanto não poderia ser executado, mas e se você puder ter esta implementação?, Por que não permitir?

O que está fazendo aí uma uma coisa chamada implementação anônima de classe, portanto há o que executar e aí você consegue instanciar a classe que acabou de criar, ainda que o tipo ainda seja o mais geral, ou seja, o tipo da interface. Portanto você está instanciando uma classe que acabou de ser criada e só pode ser usada aí já que ela sequer tem nome.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação! Vou estudar mais sobre implementação anonima de classes. Conceito novo. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 6):

Apesar de `new ActionListener()` parecer indicar que está a instanciar a interface, o que está a ser feito é declarar e ao mesmo tempo implementar e instanciar uma classe que implementa essa interface.

Essa expressão declara o que se chama *Anonymous Classes*.

As classes anónimas são como classes locais mas sem nome, ambas são *inner* classes.

Uma classe anónima pode ser uma implementação de uma interface ou uma classe herdada de outra.